# Unable to boot kubuntu 14.04/15.04 from flash drive

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, kubuntu

I was trying to install kubuntu 14.04.3 on my laptop, but I ran into some problems and wasn't able to boot it from the flash drive so far.

After loading it into the pen with Universal USB Installer, the error message was:

`(initramfs) Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs`

I searched for people who have the same problem and found these following threads

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1556602

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1850520

I've hashed the .iso, both md5 and sha1 sums are the same as found in the official download site.
I also tried 15.04, same error. Checksums match as well. 
I thought the problem could be the pen drive, but after testing it there were no errors. The pen drive has enough space too (8gb), the only problem is that it's a rather slow pen drive - itwrites at around 1,5 mb/s, but I'm not sure if that could even be a problem. I've tried with both persistent memory (1gb) and without. It's worth mentioning I've done this before with the same pen drive and the same laptop, the only difference being that I now got a SSD (Crucial BX100), which is why I'm reinstalling - however, I can't even load it live, so I assume it's not the SSD's fault either.

So, I tried using unetbootin instead of Universal USB Installer, and it's now giving me a different error*:
`(initramfs) unable to find a live medium containing a live file system`

*actually I'm not sure when this error showed up, after re-writing the .iso to the flash drive, now it just hangs after recognizing the USBs I have on, more specifically, hangs indefinitely after recognizing my webcam. It's built-in to the laptop so I can't remove it.

I found two more links, which I'm not able to paste due to not having enough reputation.

Again, the hashes match. I don't have a USB 3.0 port. I've also tried using a DVD, but just my luck, my DVD drive apparently doesn't work correctly.

I'm without ideas. I'll try using the flash drive on a friend's computer later today if I can, but if the community has any additional ideas I'd be happy. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a window tool called rufus.exe it works well with all linux distros.
after writing to usb, restart your pc, enter boot menu and chooose the usb and all will run well.

Comment: Was going to do this, and it would probably work, but first I tried the usb dongle on a friend's computer. It worked fine. Then it clicked me it could just be a priority boot thing. Selecting boot from the pen drive wouldn't work (even though it would reach the splash screen), but putting USB boot on first priority in the BIOS worked. Go figure. This was with unetbootin, still no idea why Universal USB installer didn't work this time. I'll try Rufus next time, it seems promising, thanks!